# Conversion from Hash Router to Browser Router blows up webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I was using hash router on a React website I've been developing (for no good reason) and I recently decided, for SEO purposes, to switch to `BrowserRouter`. First problem I had, the `"/public"` folder stops working, images can't be found, etc.

Second problem (more serious...) webpack is now jacked. It seems to be looking for a "main.js" in each of my component subdirectories. I haven't changed the webpack config file. For example the portfolio component generates this error.

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:9500/portfolio/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Here is the contents of `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    /** "mode"
     * the environment - development, production, none. tells webpack 
     * to use its built-in optimizations accordingly. default is production 
     */
    mode: "development", 
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
        filename: "main.js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    /** "target"
     * setting "node" as target app (server side), and setting it as "web" is 
     * for browser (client side). Default is "web"
     */
    target: "web",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    devServer: {
        port: "9500",
        static: ["./public"],
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        liveReload: true,
        /** this next line is important for react-router-dom */
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js','.jsx','.json'] 
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:  'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css)$/,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                  // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                  "style-loader",
                  // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                  "css-loader",
                  // Compiles Sass to CSS
                  "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

A commenter asked to see the html file. Here is `index.html` from the `"/public"` directory. Pretty much the webpack default.

```html
.<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>....</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I doubt that browser router is better for SEO. Most crawlers don't even load JavaScript so it really doesn't matter. Only server-side routing is detected by SEO robots

Comment: Re: BTW the error message is basically a 404 which is interpreted as "text/html" (seems obvious but thought I'd make that clear)

Comment: Can you post your HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "main.js",
    publicPath: "/public/"
},
```

This will tell webpack to include "/public/" in the URLs for your assets, so the server knows to look in the public folder for the files.